# Mongo Db schema

Tags: java, mongodb

I have to save the different profiles of a user from various social media.for example 
user may have 1 facebook and 2 twitter profile. if i save the each profile
it is inserted as a new document in different collections like facebook and twitter is a collections and how would i relate this document to another.
I used dot notation in mongodb. if i relate the facebook and twitter profile of a same user means
it is easy to fetch the record.How would i design the schema ? and also `how would i avoid duplication`? Is any possible to use the facebook id 
twitter id as unique? I am new to `mongoDB`. How would i join the documents from different collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ruby implementation, but hoping your able to translate the schema logic into your java code.

```
 class User
    has_one :facebook_profile
    has_one :twitter_profile
 end

 class TwitterProfile
    belongs_to :user 
 end

 class FacebookProfile
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

You can enforce unique indexes on the collections like so:

```
 db.twitter_profiles.ensureIndex({user_id: 1 }, {unique: true})
 db.facebook_profiles.ensureIndex({user_id: 1}, {unique: true})
```

You can use whatever field you want to enforce uniqueness at the user level.

Hope that helps.

Comment: great. but how would i enforce index after save?

Comment: You can specify { unique: true, dropDups: true } which will add the index and remove any documents that conflict with the index.

Comment: It says is not a function. I used db.user.twitter_profiles.enforceIndex({user_id: 1 }, {unique: true})   `Property 'enforceIndex' of object user.twitter_profiles is not a function
`

Comment: I used ensureIndex instead of enforceIndex

Comment: How did you fetch the values using join

Comment: You will likely need to reference your mongodb driver.